# The import org.apache cannot be resolved despite importing commons.io-2.6-bin.tar.gz in my project

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons-io

I want to use the apache commons library for a file upload use case. I downloaded the commons-io jar from 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi .

Here is the incomplete method I have written to use LineIterator class.

```
public ArrayList<Person> readFileUsingCommons(String filepath){

        ArrayList<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();
        LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(filepath, "UTF-8");
        return null;
```

Now, despite importing the binary from commons io, I am getting the error.

> LineIterator cannot be resolved to a type.

Can somebody guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It looks like you need to configure the [build path](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm) for your Eclipse project.

Comment: You still need an import statement for LineIterator.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt that is not helping.

Comment: @Abra the entry is already there.  I don't know whats causing this crazy error.

Comment: Guys, I solved it. Problem was use of .tar.gz files. So, I added a lib folder in my project. Imported the tz files and then added the jar files to the buildpath one by one. I believe @Abra was alluding to something similar. Thank you!

Comment: What is not helping? The error message that you posted indicates that you didn't have the proper import statement, else it would have mentioned the complete package name in the error message.